# How can I replace a href title to div

Tags: jquery, title

Is it possible to change a href="#" **title="ooo"** tag to div?
i try these code but not work,

this is my Htmlcode

```
<ul class="test">
    <li><a href="#" class="ut" title="ok">Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="ut" title="ok">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="ut" title="ok">Test3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="ut" title="ok">Test4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Js:

```
$('.test').each(function(){
  var title = $(this).find(".ut a").attr("title");
  $(this).find("a div").text(title);
});
```

it's should be like this:

Test1

ok

Test2

ok

Test3

ok

Test4

ok

But not Work...

http://jsfiddle.net/MotoTony/UePwj/

As always, your assistance is appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to call .each unless there is more than one element with class test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives your expected output -

http://jsfiddle.net/UePwj/7/

```
$('.test a').each(function(){
    var title = $(this).attr("title");
    $(this).parent('li').append("<div>"+title+"</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.test').each(function(){
    var title = $(this).find("a.ut").attr("title");
    $(this).find("a div").text(title);
});
```

I'm not sure what "a div" is supposed to represent, but I changed your find() function to correctly select the anchors with class "ut"